# What to keep and what to say in a 5 minutes power point presentation?

Tags: presentation, seminars, evaluation

I have a power point presentation in front of our Head regarding my research and achievements. Time limit is 4 minutes presentation and 1 minute discussion. I am wondering what to keep in the PPT?

I have now prepared with 5 slides:- an Title slide, Introduction, Ongoing Research, Achievements.

Should I keep a  Title slide? If I keep it, then how much seconds should I take and what to say in the Title slide.

What to say and how to finish up the ongoing research in 1-2 slides in a couple of minutes?

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Your question gives the impression that you've written the slides. Have you tried talking through the slides and timing yourself?

Comment: I have voted to close on the basis that this question is highly specific to your circumstances, and in particular, can't really be answered without seeing the slides that you have prepared. Give a practice talk to someone who is familiar with your work. They are far better placed to give advice.

Comment: I think this could be a reasonable question if it were more generalized, like: _When presenting a 5 minute overview of your research are there any best practices on how much time to spend on each section (intro, ongoing research, etc.)?_

Comment: For five minutes, how about NO powerpoint slides? Talk through where you and your group are at, what has been accomplished, and what is next (all big picture). Have one piece of paper to give your 'Head' with a short summary of high quality papers and invited conference talks.

Comment: I'd suggest you make the intro slide and the title slide on anf the same abd switch the order of the achievements and on going research slide. This will 1) save your bacon if you run over and they cut you short (on the assumption that your accomplishments are more valuable than your promises!) and 2) put your presentation in chronological order (ie what you've done -> what you intend to do). Good luck!

Comment: What Head? Head of your research team or head of the department who is not familiar with your research?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Head of the department and he is very much familiar with your research, however I need to make understand the other officials who are not at all familiar with your research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with 5-minute-talks. First, you have to really break down your results. Many details will get lost, depending on how many points you will address. In consequence, you will probably have to leave out important points.

Second, a one minute discussion means two good questions maximum. This is not much to elaborate in detail. Therefore, you should try to be as precise as possible listing your achievements without alluding too much to data not present in the short presentation.

Third, you really need to drop everything unnecessary. I would recommend only a title with your name, date and occasion of the talk. Don't waste any time here, get to the point. The last slide should show what you have planned for the future.

Answer (score 3):

Watch 3mt(three minute thesis) competition on youtube it will give you a very nice idea. If you want to add the title you can use it hanging behind you while you introduce yourself.